# Como mostrar os números pares de X a Y e remover "Undefined" no final

Tags: javascript

Eu preciso mostrar números pares de X a Y, sendo que X recebe 32 e Y 321, ou seja preciso mostrar os números pares de 32 a 321, porém depois da execução do meu código em JavaScript aparece "undefined", teria como remover?

[image: Mostra a mensagem indesejada no console do Chorme]

```js
function pares(x, y,) {
            for(var i = x; i <= y; i++){
                 i%2==0 ? console.log(i): 'Impar';
            }
        }
        console.log(pares(32, 321));
```

Comment: Muda o <= para <? Ou talvez te refiras ao retorno da função que é undefined?

Comment: Declare uma variável let do tipo array com os valores pares. `My.push`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todas as funções no JavaScript retornam undefined a menos que seja especificado de outra forma.

Quando você da console.log(minhaFuncao) você está dando console.log na função num todo, como o retorno dela sempre vai ser undefined se você não mudar isso, ele vai printar isso no console.

Ja com o console.log já sendo executado dentro da função, exatamente onde você quer que ele apareça, ele vai printar somente o resultado que você quer, pois é apenas o resultado e não a função em geral.

```js
function pares(x, y,) {
  for(var i = x; i <= y; i++) {
    if(i%2==0) console.log(i)
  }
}
pares(32, 321);
```